# пождскажите от чего получается подобный эффект в шаблонных классах?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я в C++ не силен, но в последнее время решил улучшить свои навыки. В процессе наткнулся на один не понятный для меня случай, буду благодарен за разъяснения от чего может быть подобный эффект:

Этот код работает без проблемм:

```
class CBase
{
protected:
    int var = 0;
};

class CDerived : public CBase
{
public :
    void print()
    {
        cout << "\nVar is: " << var;
    }
};
```

А вот с этим фрагментом кода - у меня возникают проблемы:

```
    template<typename ...T>
    class CBase
    {
    protected:
        int var = 0;
    };

    template<typename ...T>
    class CDerived : public CBase<T...>
    {
    public :
        void print()
        {
            cout << "\nVar is: " << var;
        }
    };
```

> error: ‘var’ was not declared in this scope
>            cout << "\nVar is: " << var;

т.е. как только я сделал классы шаблонными - так он сразу же перестал видеть protected переменную из базового класса

Разъясните от чего происходит подобное ? Ведь переменная var в обоих случаях помечена как protected.

Comment: Напишите `<< CBase<T...>::var;`

Comment: @Harry А почуму в шаблонном классе к protected переменной можно обратиться только указав полный путь к ней через базовый класс ?

Comment: Можно еще внести имя в класс - `using CBase<T...>::var;`, и тогда просто с `var`. А вот почему именно - не помню :(, иначе бы писал не комментарий, а ответ :) Что-то в голове вертится, но не помню точно, какое-то там сокрытие... Словом, подойдут гуру в тонкостях стандарта - расскажут...

Comment: Достаточно и `this->var`

Comment: @Harry было бы интересно гуру послушать) пригласите кого нибудь если знаете подобных, за ответ спасибо

Comment: Вопрос уже много раз задавался и отвечался.

Comment: @AnT, так и будет, потому что каждый раз описывают "симптомы", по имени "заболевание" вряд ли кто-то назовет.